# Angular ngFor, pass a multiple parameter function to pipe

Tags: angular, function, pipe, parameter-passing

I'm using the 'where' pipe at this link:

https://github.com/fknop/angular-pipes/blob/master/docs/array.md#where

which can be used with a function like this:

```
const values = [{
    a: 1,
    c: {
        d: 3,
        e: {
            f: 4
        }
    }
}, {
    a: 2,
    c: {
        d: 4,
        e: {
            f: 5
        }
    }
}];

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4];

// ...

aEqualsOne(item) {
    return item.a === 1;
}

//usage example :
{{ values | where: aEqualsOne }} <!-- [{ a: 1, c: { d: 3, e: { f: 4 } }] -->
```

Now I have this ngFor:

```
<card  *ngFor="let num of listOfNum | where: checkNum></card>
```

with this function in the component:

```
checkNum(num) {
    console.log(num);
    return num > 10;
}
```

but I have to modify the function to accept another parameter:

```
checkNum(num, k) {
    console.log(num + " > " + k + "?");
    return num > k;
}
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to pass both the item of the list and 'k' to the function passed to the pipe:

I tried with:

```
<card  *ngFor="let num of listOfNum | where: checkNum(k)></card>

<card  *ngFor="let num of listOfNum | where: checkNum(num, k)></card>
```

but no success for now..

What should I do?

Comment: _"I have to modify the function to accept another parameter"_ Or you create a function that takes the value from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Modify :

```
<card  *ngFor="let num of listOfNum | where: checkNum(k)></card>
```

to :

```
<card  *ngFor="let num of listOfNum | where: checkNum : k></card>
```

Comment: not working :( from the logs of the function checkNum it seems that the 'k' value is some sort of index (as it goes from 0 to the length of the list)